# Carrierwave 503 on image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm getting a 503 on uploading an image from my iPhone app.

I get linked to this page in the response: http://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html

But afterwards, I can view the image fine.

I set my permissions to only include me & authorized users.